# How to take the first letter of a string pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

First of all, I know it is such a common topic that I can find millions of example. Yet, I still did not understand the idea. So please forgive me about asking this for a million time.

```
char *char_name = strtok(NULL,","); // Which gives me a part of the string such as "Albert"
char** map; // Which is actually a board game representation.
```

So let me explain what I try to understand. Column and row integers are given, let us say. Then I need to change that position's character to the first character of the char *char_name, which is 'A' in the 'Albert' example.

```
map[row][column] = char_name[0]; // Does not work since char_name is a pointer.
```

Believe me, I tried almost everything I saw in internet.Thus, I do not want to bore you with my random attempts. Yet, still does not work. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens, what errors do you get, etc?

Comment: I am really new at this, forgive me. It gives me segmentation fault. I will add the whole code.

Comment: You did not provide a [mcve]. From what I see I would guess you never actually allocated memory for `map`, or you *actually* fed `strtok()` a `NULL` and a `","` and expected it to magically come up with "Albert". ;-) `char_name[0]` should work.

Comment: Re "*I will add the whole code.*", It should a *minimal* demonstration of the problem. But it should also be *runnable*. This means any input required to reproduce the problem need to be provided. Also, do provide the output you get, and the output you expect/desire. And don't forget to enable and heed warnings. (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`.)

Comment: `do not want to bore you with my random attempts`..no that will actually help us to help you.

Comment: `map[row][column] = char_name[0]; // Does not work since char_name is a pointer.` Your comment is halfway correct but incomplete. `char_name` is a pointer, but the `[]` operator _dereferences_ that pointer at the specified index (0 in this case), which is a `char`. Likewise, with `map` being a double pointer, the double bracket operators `[][]` dereference the double pointer twice, producing a `char`. There is nothing wrong with this assignment, the error is in code not shown. As others have mentioned, you must provide a [mre] for further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see how good my crystal ball is today. (I felt like it.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GRIDSIZE 10

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char * input;
    char * char_name;

    size_t row;
    size_t col;

    char ** map;

    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        puts( "Please give one string of comma-separated names as parameter." );
        return 0;
    }

    // Allocate memory
    input = malloc( strlen( argv[1] ) + 1 );
    strcpy( input, argv[1] );

    map = malloc( sizeof( char * ) * GRIDSIZE ); // memory for GRIDSIZE rows

    for ( row = 0; row < GRIDSIZE; ++row )
    {
        map[row] = malloc( GRIDSIZE ); // memory for GRIDSIZE columns
        memset( map[row], ' ', GRIDSIZE );
    }

    // Place characters
    char_name = strtok( input, "," );
    row = 0;
    col = 0;

    while ( ( char_name != NULL ) && ( row < GRIDSIZE ) )
    {
        map[row][col] = char_name[0];
        ++row;
        char_name = strtok( NULL, "," );
    }

    // Print grid
    for ( row = 0; row < GRIDSIZE; ++row )
    {
        for ( col = 0; col < GRIDSIZE; ++col )
        {
            printf( "%c.", map[row][col] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    // Free memory
    for ( row = 0; row < GRIDSIZE; ++row )
    {
        free( map[row] );
    }

    free( map );
    free( input );
}
```

(Version 2, taking input from command line.)

I omitted all the checks if `malloc()` returned non-NULL, which should be in there if you are writing something non-trivial.

Input:

```
myprog "Albert,Berta"
```

Output:

```
A. . . . . . . . . .
B. . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
```